# Conditional breakpoint not firing in lldb

Tags: ios, debugging, lldb

I am attempting to find the exact instant when a UILabel is set the with value "--- points". This certainly does occur within the program, but the breakpoint is not triggered.

Simulator is running on 64bit, which means $arg1, $arg2, etc shortcut registers are populated by lldb.

**Breakpoint command:**

`` breakpoint set -r "setText:" -c `(BOOL)[(NSString*) $arg3 isEqual:@"-- points"]` ``

Entering this command returns successfully with the message "29 Locations"

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Check with `isEqualToString:`

Comment: Thanks, tried br s -r "setText:" -c ```(BOOL)[(NSString*) $arg3 isEqualToString:@"-- points"] ```  and still not firing :(

Comment: Breakpoint conditions are just expressions that should evaluate to some truth value.  But the breakpoint conditions are evaluated in a place in lldb  where it's pretty hard to return a good error if the expression fails to parse, or falls over for some other reason.  So the best way to troubleshoot this sort of problem is to first make sure the expression parses when you are stopped at the breakpoint, using the lldb console & lldb's "expr" command.  Do you get an error when you try to do that, and if so, what?